# Scrapy - Issue with xpath on an xml crawl

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to make a simple spider to grab some xml and spit it out in a new format for an experiment. However it seems there is extra code contained within the xml which is spat out. The format I want is like this (no extra code or value tag) along the lines of this: `<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>`

I think I am using xpath wrong but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Spider

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from crawler.items import CrawlerItem

class SiteSpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'site'
    allowed_domains = ['www.w3schools.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml']
    itertag = 'note'

    def parse_node(self, response):
        xxs = XmlXPathSelector(response)
        to = xxs.select('//to')
        who = xxs.select('//from')
        heading = xxs.select('//heading')   
        body = xxs.select('//body')           
        return item
```

Input

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Curreont (wrong) Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item>
      <body>
         <value>&lt;body&gt;Don't forget me this weekend!&lt;/body&gt;</value>
      </body>
      <to>
         <value>&lt;to&gt;Tove&lt;/to&gt;</value>
      </to>
      <who>
         <value>&lt;from&gt;Jani&lt;/from&gt;</value>
      </who>
      <heading>
         <value>&lt;heading&gt;Reminder&lt;/heading&gt;</value>
      </heading>
   </item>
</items>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of [`parse_node()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.XMLFeedSpider.parse_node) is incorrect. There should be `selector` argument given which you should call `xpath()` method on, example:

```
def parse_node(self, response, selector):
    to = selector.xpath('//to/text()').extract()
    who = selector.xpath('//from/text()').extract()
    print to, who
```

Prints:

```
[u'Tove'] [u'Jani']
```

Comment: This seems to give me this error: ```File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/depth.py", line 50, in <genexpr>
     return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spiders/feed.py", line 62, in parse_nodes
     ret = iterate_spider_output(self.parse_node(response, selector))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spiders/feed.py", line 51, in parse_node
     raise NotImplementedError
 exceptions.NotImplementedError: ```

Comment: @JamesWillson please check the indentation and make sure there is a `parse_node()` method defined inside your spider class. If the issue persists, let me know what scrapy version you are using and show your current code. Thanks.

Comment: I'm stil struggling I'm afraid, i've put all the code here, is there any chance you could have a little look: https://gist.github.com/employ/b2a286762e2a6807d44b

Comment: @JamesWillson yeah, you should indent `parse_node()`.

Comment: I see, sorry, i just figured that out myself. Thank you very much